# OpenSSL - access a file-BIO via memory

Tags: c, openssl

I try to access the bytes of a BIO with BUF_MEM.
But it is not working if it is a file-BIO.

```
    BUF_MEM *bmmem = NULL, bmfil = NULL;
    int ret = -1;

    // OK for memory
    BIO *biomem = BIO_new (BIO_s_mem ());       
    ret = BIO_get_mem_ptr (biomem, &bmmem);    // ret = 1
    printf ("\nbiomem - %d %d", ret, bmmem);   // OK

    // NOK for file
    BIO *biofil = BIO_new (BIO_s_file ());
    BIO_read_filename (biofil, "myfile.pem");   // ok
    ret = BIO_get_mem_ptr (biofil, &bmfil);     // ret = 0
    printf ("\nbiofil - %d %d, ret, bmfil);     // NOK
```

Do I miss something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BIO_get_mem_ptr` gives you a pointer into the underlying memory buffer of a mem bio. It only works with a mem BIO. In a file BIO there is no underlying memory buffer!

Use `BIO_read` to read data out of a BIO. That works on both a mem BIO and a file BIO.

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/BIO_read.html

Comment: That worked but I need the BIO originally for some other function.
So after I BIO_read it is invalid for the later usage. I tried BIO_reset and BIO_seek (bio, 0) but nothing helped. Do I need to open it again or is there a way to access it without changing.

Comment: The behaviour of BIO_reset() is to reset the BIO to some initial state. The actual behaviour will depend on what the underlying BIO is. The docs say this about calling `BIO_reset` on a file BIO: `BIO_reset() attempts to change the file pointer to the start of file
using fseek(stream, 0, 0).` But for a mem bio they say: `Calling BIO_reset() on a read write memory BIO clears any data in it if the
flag BIO_FLAGS_NONCLEAR_RST is not set.`. If you want to retain the data you could try calling `BIO_set_flags() and pass in the BIO_FLAGS_NONCLEAR_RST flag.